# Cannot close window using VBS

Tags: vbscript

I want to start a program and then close it, not kill it, with Ctrl+W to send it to the system tray.  My script is:

```
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
exeName = "d:\MyProgram.exe"
wshShell.Run exeName
Wscript.Sleep 10000


strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'MyProgram.exe'")
'Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
For Each objProcess in colProcesses
    Wscript.Sleep 3000
    wshShell.AppActivate(objProcess.ProcessID)
    wshShell.SendKeys "^{w}"
Next
Set wshShell = nothing
Set objWMIService = nothing
```

My issue is the program window is not being activated and closed.  However if I run the program first manually, delete the run command (wshShell.Run exeName) in the script and then run the script the program is set Active and Ctrl+W is sent and the window is closed.

Why can't I start and close the program via the one script?

TIA